# Find segment length $x$ from two identical overlapping squares

Tags: geometry, solution-verification

I have the following picture:

$\hspace{4.5cm}$[image: Two squares]

---

Considering only lengths AN = 30 and LM = 10 are given, ***x is needed to be found*** (RM on the picture).

I started the problem based on triangle similarities (3 angles the same, so the proportion of the sides should be the same) and if I note the length of a square as **len** then I figured:

(len - 30) : (len - NP) = NP : 30

where **len - 30** is NB.

So **30*(len - 30) = NP*(len-NP)**

And from that I get that NP is equal to 30 and that is equal to **len** which cannot be from the picture. Am I doing something wrong and could x be found?

Comment: Please make the picture small..

Comment: after the link you have, simply add a "m" to make medium dimensions

Comment: all done, thanks.

Comment: @anicicn Consider the right triangle APN. The leg NP must be smaller than the hypotenuse, 30.  Consider the equation $30(\text{len}-30) = \text{NP}(\text{len}-\text{NP}).$  Manipulate the equation into a quadratic equation in NP, and then solve for NP.

Comment: Note that all six right triangles in that figure are similar among them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

Let the unknown variable be the angle $\theta$. Then, all the segment lengths can be computed successively. They are all given in the diagram. Matching the left and right side lengths of the upright square to get

$$30+30\cos\theta = 30(1-\sin\theta) + 10 + 30(1+\cos\theta-\sin\theta)\tan\theta$$

which simplifies to

$$3(1-\sin\theta)=\cos\theta$$

Solve to get $\cos\theta=\frac35$ and $\sin\theta =\frac45$. Thus,

$$x= 30(1+\cos\theta-\sin\theta)\sec\theta=40$$

Answer (score 0):

HINT.

From the similitude of triangles $APN$ and $RBN$ one gets:
$$
{AN\over RN}={PN\over BN}=r,
\quad\text{that is:}\quad
AN=r\cdot RN,\quad PN=r\cdot BN.
$$
Substituting that into $PN+RN=AN+BN$ one obtains:
$$
RN(1-r)=BN(1-r).
$$
As $RN>BN$, it follows that $r=1$, that is:
$$
AN=RN,\quad PN=BN.
$$

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the explanation. 
I have come, in the meantime, to that conclusion but still cannot figure out how to get to the value of x.

Comment: For example, I came to find that is x = 60*len/(120 - len)